# Change Assistant Language Without Changing Locale on Oreo

Tags: localization, text-to-speech, google-assistant, 8.1-oreo

I am in the United States, but I would like it if my assistant and navigation voice had an Australian accent. On Oreo, the only way to do this seems to be to change the system language to English(Australia). After doing this though, I notice the phone seems to think I am Australian, as Google Now shows me news from Australian websites and Inbox shows dates in DD/MM format. There used to be an option to change date format, but that also seems to have disappeared in recent versions. I would like it if my Assistant voice were Australian, but my overall system local was US. Does anyone know of a way to make this happen?

Comment: I just downloaded Google assistant app to see if it can be changed. Sorry, it says that Google assistant language is tied to the system language. In short, you can't

Comment: That's on an unrooted device -couldn't find workaround for rooted devices too

Comment: Did you try under Assistant settings, there is an option for search language.

Comment: A bochur, that setting does not affect the assistant language. Though I set it to English(US) so I may hopefully get slightly better voice recognition.